# Understanding Type Parameters in Typeclass Declarations

Tags: haskell, monads, typeclass

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what the type parameters indicate in the case of the State monad, but also for the other mtl monads as well. Insofar as I understand it, when I compose a State monad, as in `State String Int`, what I really have is `StateT String Identity Int`. In the case of the method `get` for the `MonadState` typeclass, it returns `m s`, what is the 'm' in this case? Is it the Identity monad, Identity Int? And in this case is the 's' which represents the type of the state a parameter to the 'm'?

Thank you, I'm obviously having a bit of trouble understanding Haskell's type system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well it depends on what instance you use – that's the whole point of the type class!

```
class MonadState s m where
  get :: m s
```

In case of simply `State`, that's the monad you're in:

```
instance MonadState String (State String) where
  get :: State String String
```

...which is short for

```
instance MonadState String (StateT String Identity) where
  get :: (StateT String Identity) String
```

OTOH, it could also be

```
instance MonadState Int (StateT Int IO) where
  get :: StateT Int IO Int
```

Comment: Okay, thank you, this answers my question, and I understand the example now. Now I just need to learn more about Transformers!

Answer (score 3):

If we look at the definition of `StateT`:

```
class (Monad m) => MonadState s m | m -> s where
    get :: m s
    put :: s -> m ()
```

Which has an instance for `StateT` defined as

```
instance (Monad m) => MonadState s (StateT s m) where
    get = StateT.get
    put = StateT.put
```

Then we say that

```
type State s a = StateT s Identity a
```

then we know that in this case, `m ~ Identity`.  For your case of `State String Int`, we can also infer that `s ~ String` and `a ~ Int`, so the type of `get` is `Identity String` and the type of `put` is `Identity ()`.